# Can I call into C# from Unity iOS Plugin and get a return type?

Tags: c#, ios, plugins, unity-game-engine, wrapper

I'm currently using `UnitySendMessage(Class, Method, StringArg)` to call from my iOS code back to C#.

However, I'm trying to implement something now that requires the return value from that method. I'm implementing a delegate that the C# code can use which wraps the native Objective-C wrapper.

`UnitySendMessage` has a 1 frame delay and is asynchronous, so isn't suitable for this. What can/should I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling from iOS code to Unity C# code is an asynchronous call meaning you cannot have a return value. What you can do is Call a Unity C# method from iOS and for the response (return value) call an iOS method from Unity C# and perform your return value processing in this iOS method.

it will be more like:

> iOS (method1) ---- Data -----> C# (methodX)
>
> stop any processing on iOS side
>
> C# (methodX) ---- response -----> iOS (method2)
>
> Do some processing on response in method2

Comment: Hmm, if I pause to wait for that, because the return needs to be synchronous, I'll be freezing the unity game right?

Comment: Calling a method from C# to iOS can block the game. but calling from iOS to C# it is always asynchronous waiting in iOS will not block the game but you can not get return value from `UnitySendMessage`. You will have to get the return value by calling another iOS method from C#.

Comment: Yeah but delegates are strictly synchronous, so I can't use your technique I don't think? Unless I'm missing something

Comment: Where do you plan to use delegates? I am not talking about using delegate there is a way of calling iOS methods from C# although a little different from `UnitySendMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a way to call from native code into Unity that is not asynchronous.

The way I have done similiar to your scenario is to have C# poll native code every frame and then again with the response:

```
Unity         Native
  |---GetInfo()--->|
process            |
  |---Result()---->|
```